# Problemas con hooks en react

Tags: reactjs

estoy intentando modificar el estado de una variable users que almacena un array vacio cosa que cuando se renderice la vista se llame al metodo `fetchData` y a traves de un forEach recorra el array que me retorna de la collection de firebase y pueda mostrar los nombres en la pagina, pero no se porque cuando se llama el metodo, es como si useEffect tomara el array vacio y colocara el primer elemento del array que me retorna y asi..

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import db from './config';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async() => {
    console.log('fetching ...');
    const response = db.collection('users');
    const data = await response.get();
    let a = [];
    data.docs.forEach((item) => {
      a.push(item.data());
      setUsers([...users, item.data()]);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return(
    <div>
      <h4>users:</h4>
      {users && users.map((usr, ix) => {
        return(
          <p key={ix}>name: {usr.age}</p>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, siempre alimenta el array de la variable users con el mismo objeto cada vez que hay un cambio en la vista, y no actualiza de una `fetchData()` el estado de la variable users

Comment: No entiendo porqué la necesidad de setear el estado dentro del `forEach`. Me parece que de esa forma seteas el estado varias veces de forma innecesaria. ¿No sería mejor hacerlo afuera del `forEach`? Creo que podrías simplemente setearlo solo una vez afuera del `forEach` con los datos del `a` al que le venís haciendo `.push` así: `setUsers(a)`.

Comment: Lo que podria hacer es tomar el array de objetos que me llega de la peticion y almacenarlo en a  como a = [...a, arrayLLegado], a eso te refieres?.

Comment: Ahí lo agregué como una respuesta. Así lo puedo explicar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Al final termine usando un componente de clase, la verdad con hooks me dio mas problemas que certezas jaja

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import db from './config';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async() => {
  
    const response = db.collection('users');
    const data = await response.get();
    data.docs.forEach((item) => {
      this.setState({
        users: this.state.users.concat(item.data())
      })
    });
  }

  render(){
    const { users } = this.state;
    return(
      users.map((usr) => {
        return(
          <p>{usr.name}</p>
        )
      })
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: aun así, voy a darle importancia resolviendo tu componente funcional

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la respuesta de la base de datos es un array, mi propuesta para resolver este problema es la siguiente:

En el `fetchData` cambiamos la manera de pasar al estado los datos de la consulta.

No seteamos el estado por cada vez que se itera el `forEach`, si no más bien hacemos un `.push` en el nuevo array llamado `a` por cada elemento.

Luego de rellenar ese array, fuera del `forEach`, recién ahí seteamos el estado haciendo `setUsers(a)`.

Al actualizar el estado, yo no veo la necesidad de poner el `a` dentro de otro array  porque `a` ya es un array. Tampoco termino de entender el motivo de usar algo como `...a` en este caso, y sospecho que eso es lo que genera el error.

Con esos cambios, `fetchData` quedaría así:

```
const fetchData = async() => {
  console.log('fetching ...');
  const response = db.collection('users');
  const data = await response.get();
  let a = [];
  data.docs.forEach((item) => {
    a.push(item.data());
  });
  setUsers(a);
}
```